# Tkinter executes commands in a different sequence than it says in code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

why does the program execute the other function before the labeler-function?

```
from tkinter import *
geni = "generating processes"
...
def labeler(texti):
    activit = Label(graphics,text=texti)
    activit.grid(row=0,column=2)
...
button_1=Button(graphics,text="xy!", command=lambda:[labeler(geni),otherFunction()])
...
```

Comment: that's the thing about UI programming. There is no sequential execution

Comment: that's more like why `lambda:[f1(),f2()]` doesn't evaluate in that order

Comment: How are you determining what order `labeler()` is executed in?  It does *nothing* that has an immediate visible effect, changes to widgets are only processed when you return to the `.mainloop()` (or explicitly call one of Tkinter's update functions).

Comment: why are you using a complex lambda rather than creating a proper function? As you're seeing, lambdas are hard to debug.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. The short answer is "tkinter always executes code in the order that you specify". If it _appears_ that it's not, it's because of your code. If we can't see code that reproduces the behavior it's going to be hard for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I used this as minimal example:

```
from tkinter import *

def fibo(n):
    if n < 1: return 1
    else: return fibo(n-2)+fibo(n-1)

def fun1():
    print("1:", fibo(20))

def fun2():
    print("2:", fibo(19))

root = Tk()
btn = Button(root, text="Test", command=lambda:[fun1(),fun2()])

btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This produces on click

```
python tk.py 
1: 17711
2: 10946
```

Comment: AFAIK, both `fun1()`, `fun2()` get executed on different threads. In your case since both the functions were small and simple, they did execute sequentially. If there were to be a computationally complex code in `fun1()`, I think 2 would be printed first. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I have no clue why both functions could be executed on different thread. The interpreter runs on one thread and the issue does come from calling `lambda:[f1(),f2()]()` and arrays are evaluated left to right.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order for more info on evaluation order.

Comment: @learner: _"AFAIK, both fun1(), fun2() get executed on different threads."_ - that is false. Tkinter by defalut is single threaded. They both get executed in the main thread. _"I think 2 would be printed first. Please correct me if I'm wrong"_ - you are wrong. They will always execute in the order specified.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @BryanOakley